# Read only file can be written through the network

Tags: networking, readonly

I have a text file for which I have set `chmod 444 file` and I effectively see `-r--r--r-- 1 blah blah  310 Aug 27 20:00 file` with `ls -ls`. If I try to write on this file e.g. with `nano` I cant, this is fine. However, if I open the file through the network with [Geany](https://www.geany.org/)¹ then it can write it without any problem. Should I expect this? How can I make the file read only? I want to avoid myself accidentally changing it.

¹ Not sure how this works or the details, I just connect to that computer through the network using my file explorer writing in the address bar `sftp://user@computer.institution.blah/home/user/path_to_somewhere` and then I double click on the file, to open it with Geany.

Comment: Run the command `ls -li` on the file before and after your Geany editing session.  Does the inode (the large number before the `-r--r--r--` permissions) change?

Comment: Yes, it does change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chattr +i filename
```

should do the job, if your file is on a file system that supports the immutable flag.

Comment: For completenes, I had to run this with `sudo`. Otherwise it would complain `chattr: Operation not permitted while setting flags on deleteme.txt`. And to make it editable again change `+i`→`-i`.

Answer (score 3):

What's happening is Geany is doing what many file editors do:  When you make changes and save the file, it writes the new version of the contents into a new file, and then deletes the original file and changes the new file's name and permissions to match the old file.  This is why your original file seemed to change inode when Geany changed it - it's was replaced by a new file.

The permissions on the directory allow these actions, even if the permissions on the original file appear to prohibit them.

You have already successfully tried making the original file immutable.  Another potential solution (if `chattr +i` were not available or had other undesirable side effects) would be to see if Geany has a configuration option that tells it to not update files that are not writable, even when the directory permissions allow it.  Trying to adjust the directory permissions to prevent deletion and renaming of its files is difficult to do without undesirable side effects.